# No opt-out option from App Signing in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

I'm trying to opt out from App signing in Play Console but there is no option to opt-out. As you can see in pictures i have Change signing key but not opt out. Even when i open Change Signing Key i'm given option to upload my key but not to opt out. Is there any possibility to opt out now or this is mandatory and opt-out is not an option anymore?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading Google's Play Console Help article on **Use Play App Signing** there is a paragraph that states:

> **Note:** For apps created before August 2021, you can still upload an APK and manage your own keys instead of using Play App Signing and publishing with an Android App Bundle

To me that reads from August 2021 (i.e. now), you won't be able to upload an APK **and** you also won't be able to manage your own keys. They should probably have split that sentence into two to make it clear that both options will no longer be available from August 2021.

Here's the link for reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756